# How to identify EXACTLY the error type in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange, error-messaging

I have a spreadsheet which I need to import several data from other spreadsheets, So I have `=importrange(<theOtherFile>,<cell>)` in different places. But I have to go, one by one allowing access the first time my file is created.

What I want is to have an a different sheet a list with all the document references I link in the document. Over there, there is a list of all documents including Google Docs and Google Presentations. Then a script creates a `=importrange()` for each of them so I can, in one shot, press "Allow Access" once for each file (and the needed values pop up in the other places).

The problem is that in this huge list of importranges, I cannot tell apart `#REF` errors because I still don't have permission to collect data from the file or because the file is not a spreadsheet at all ("Spreadsheet cannot be found." error).

So, my question is: can I, beforehand, tell apart Google Sheets from other types of files so my script doesn't try to import them? If not; Can I somehow interact with the error message of a `#REF` error (this way I could write a formula that cleans the cell if the `importrange()` failed because the file is not a spreadsheet at all)?

Answer (score 2):

`=ERROR.TYPE(A1)`

```
#NULL!  1
#DIV/0! 2
#VALUE! 3
#REF!   4
#NAME?  5
#NUM!   6
#N/A    7
#ERROR! 8
(no error) #N/A
```

if a cell has no error, the `ERROR.TYPE` gives an error. Use:

`=IFERROR(ERROR.TYPE(B11);"No error")`

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets offers only two functions to nullify the errors:

- `IFERROR` - Returns the first argument if it is not an error value, otherwise returns the second argument if present, or a blank if the second argument is absent.
- `IFNA` - Returns the first argument if it is not an `#N/A` error value, otherwise returns the second argument if present, or a blank if the second argument is absent.

to analyze the error you can use:

- `ERROR.TYPE` - Returns a number corresponding to the error value in a different cell.
- `ISREF` - Checks whether a value is a valid cell reference.
- `ISNA` - Checks whether a value is the error `#N/A`.
- `ISERR` - Checks whether a value is an error other than `#N/A`
- `ISERROR` - Checks whether a value is an error.